# I forgot my localhost mediawiki installation password. I remember the account name. Where do I find the data where the password and account name is?

Tags: mediawiki

Another alternative for me is to reset the account installation meanwhile retaining the files. I have the files but the login page is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ChangePassword.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ChangePassword.php) to set a new password for any user.

Of course, the old password is not stored anywhere. Its salted hash, from which the password cannot be restored, is in the `user_password` field of the [`User`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_table) table.